# Hash added into a POST http request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to integrate a hash into my database, which is generated by a POST request when creating a new user.

The APIs being new to me, I don't really understand the error and why my code failed. Is someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I could make this work ?

Here's the code I wrote :

Controller

```cs
//POST:         api/user/
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<User> PostUserItem(User user)
        {
            string Hash = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(1000, 9999).ToString();
            SHA512 sha512 = SHA512.Create(Hash);
            string Hashed = sha512.ToString();
            user.Token_Validation = Hashed;
            _context.UserItems.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetUserItem", new User{idUser=user.idUser}, user);
        }
```

Model

```cs
[Table("USERS")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int idUser { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string pwd { get; set; }
        public string Token_Validation { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext

```cs
public class RouteContext : DbContext
    {
        public RouteContext(DbContextOptions<RouteContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<User> UserItems { get; set; }
    }
```

And here's the ERROR 500 I got when trying to use my API

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LocalBeers.Controllers.UserController.PostUserItem(User user) in /var/www/html/backend/Controllers/UserController.cs:line 46
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: It looks like `user` is null to me, which would imply it isn't getting populated during model binding, probably because the POST request you're submitting to trigger this controller is badly formed in some way.  Can you set a breakpoint on the `string Hash = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(1000, 9999).ToString();` line and inspect the value of `user`?

Comment: But why a `hash` of a random number?

Comment: @FrankNielsen It looks like a validation token.

Comment: @rfmodulator true, but the random number itself, or a `Guid.NewGuid()` will be just as good. The `hash` makes sense if it was used on the password - that is saved in plain text.

Comment: @FrankNielsen There are lots of things that would be *just as good*. That doesn't make this less good, except the limited range of values specified.

Comment: CluPixels, Instead of 1000 to 9999... be sure to use a **much** larger range of values in the final version, that's only 9000 possible attempts to circumvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
string Hash = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(1000, 9999).ToString();
SHA512 sha512 = SHA512.Create(Hash);
```

...At this point, `sha512` is `null` and the next line throws `NullReferenceException` which causes the server to return an HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) status.

The `SHA512.Create(String)` overload expects the name of an implementation, *not* the data you want to hash.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha512.create?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_SHA512_Create_System_String_).

Instead, try something like this:

```
var random = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(1000, 9999).ToString();

string hashed = string.Empty;

using (SHA512 sha512 = SHA512.Create())
{
    var hashValue = sha512.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(random));

    hashed = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
}

user.Token_Validation = hashed;
```

Comment: I've used the code you gave me, and it's still returning me an error 500, but not the same as before :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
```

Comment: @CluPixels That's a configuration issue, I do suggest you web search that one.

Comment: @CluPixels This line `return CreatedAtAction("GetUserItem", new User{idUser=user.idUser}, user);` is probably suspect.